# Jquery Validate conditional date compare

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

Have the following validation for date comparison, which works when invalid dates are entered i.e. end date is before start date. But the problem is that the validation also kicks in when no dates are entered.

I only want to use the validation if both start and end date are entered.

```
 $j("#Form1").validate(
    {

        rules:
            {
                content_0$leftcolumn_0$whiteboxplaceholder_0$exportFilterFromActivityDate: {
                    date: true,
                    required: false
                },
                content_0$leftcolumn_0$whiteboxplaceholder_0$exportFilterToActivityDate: {
                    date: true,
                    required: false,
                    isAfterStartDate: "#content_0_leftcolumn_0_whiteboxplaceholder_0_exportFilterFromActivityDate"
                },
                content_0$leftcolumn_0$whiteboxplaceholder_0$exportFilterFromFinalApprovalDate: {
                    date: true,
                    required: false
                },
                content_0$leftcolumn_0$whiteboxplaceholder_0$exportFilterToFinalApprovalDate: {
                    date: true,
                    required: false,
                    isAfterStartDate: "#content_0_leftcolumn_0_whiteboxplaceholder_0_exportFilterFromFinalApprovalDate"
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe use a conditional function first?

```
if( ($('#dateA').val()!='') && ($('#dateB').val()!='') ){

    $j("#Form1").validate({Validate....});

}
```